# How to check if vectors of a dataframe are NULL to not apply in the function?

Tags: r, lapply

I have this function to calculate whatever variables I have in the inputs to return some stats. However, I wanted to put a group of standard vectors in a standard script but depending on the situation, I might have it or not have those set of vectors.

```
calc_stats_table <- function(
  ..., decimal_places = 3
){
  data
  data <- data.frame(...)
  df <-
    as.data.frame(t(data.frame(lapply(data,
                        function(x)
                          rbind(
                            average = round(mean(x, na.rm = T),
                                         decimal_places),
                            minimum = round(min(x, na.rm = T),
                                            decimal_places),
                            maximum = round(max(x, na.rm = T),
                                            decimal_places)
                          )))))
  return(df)
}
```

Is it possible to have some kind of check or condition inside of the function to not apply lapply in the vectors that are NULL?

Edit:
Imagine I have this defined but sometimes I dont have all 3 signals. Just one or two but it is set like this since it is a standardized script used by multiple users.

```
calc_stats_table(
    "Primary anemometer average" = data$ws_refmast_prim_avg,
    'Primary anemometer minimum' = data$ws_refmast_prim_min,
    'Primary anemometer maximum' = data$ws_refmast_prim_max
                )
```

The error that returns when I dont have a specific signal is

```
Error in data.frame(...) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 39949, 0
```

2nd Edit:

I am now trying to do something similar to a list instead of a dataframe but applying @Roland approach it doesnt work.

```
SiteCond_list <- list(
  "inflow_vs_tod" = inflow_vs_tod,
  "inflow_vs_ws" = inflow_vs_ws,
  "inflow_vs_wd" = inflow_vs_wd
)
```

I get this error

```
Error: object 'inflow_vs_ws' not found
```

Comment: maybe `if(all(is.null(...))); next`? your question is not quite clear. please give us a short example of how your data is structured so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: I don't understand the question. `lapply` will iterate over whatever is in the data.frame. It doesn't care about what is not in the data.frame. So, your issue is likely with how you call the function. But you don't show that. (Why do you have a stray `data` in the beginning of the function body?)

Comment: I edited the question. Hope it is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your input into list:

```
input <- list(
    "Primary anemometer average" = data[["ws_refmast_prim_avg"]],
    'Primary anemometer minimum' = data[["ws_refmast_prim_min"]],
    'Primary anemometer maximum' = data[["ws_refmast_prim_max"]]
                )
```

Then remove `NULL` elements:

```
input <- input[lengths(input) > 0]
```

And call the function:

```
do.call(calc_stats_table, input)
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense for sure! But is it possible to do something inside of the function? I would guess not since for that we would insert NULL inputs in the function and that is impossible to not return an error...

Comment: This preety much solved and it wasn´t to much to add to the code. Thanks and good solution.

Comment: Do you know how can I apply a similar procedure to a list of dataframes instead of vectors? I tried this aproach but it returns "Error: object not found"